# Two column layout side by side using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is a jQuery code snippet to produce a two column layout (http://jsfiddle.net/G7Uk2/6/):

```
total_menu_item = Math.round(($('div.footer-menu-item').length)/2);
var fi = $(".footer-menu-item");
fi.remove();
for(var i=0;i<total_menu_item;i++){
    fi.eq(i).css("clear","both").appendTo(".footer-content-column-one");
    fi.eq(i+total_menu_item).appendTo(".footer-content-column-one");
}
```

In the code above, the layout will be:

1  10

2  11

3  12

4  13

5  14

6  15

7  16

8  17

9

How can I modify the code above to create the following layout?

1  2

3  4

5  6

7  8

9 ...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: add a "display: inline-block" in the .footer-menu-item class and remove the js. check it here http://jsfiddle.net/G7Uk2/8/

Comment: @Sushil. Thanks for your comment. I am using a similar css code for two layout. Is there a way to eliminate the margin-left and margin-right for each line? Please see http://jsfiddle.net/G7Uk2/23/ OR http://jsfiddle.net/G7Uk2/21/

Comment: @Sushil. I decided to add an index number (within a while statement) to insert a class element such as "odd" and "even" to provide proper margins. Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry was out. let me see the fiddle

Comment: so did you use jquery?

Comment: @Sushil. For the time being, I will use such css code snippets as you suggested. I added a separate class elements such as "left" and "right" (within a wile statement) for fine-tuning the layout. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: you're most welcome @Peter . glad was able to help